# Why would a low power PSU damage your PC?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power

I've just been reading [this article](http://www.pcgamer.com/crysis-reinstall-does-the-graphical-powerhouse-hold-up-today/) on PC Gamer, and in the first paragraph the writer says that he hooked up a low power PSU to a powerful graphics card to play Crysis. After a few minutes, something exploded inside. I can understand why a component would explode if too much power was surging through it, but why would a card explode if the power being supplied to it was insufficient?

Comment: The article's pretty crap, and the author is unclear. I can totally see PSU components blowing with excessive draw - and he's pretty much "the magic smoke exploded and my PC died :() as opposed to talking about where the scorchmarks were.

Comment: "[I] had hooked up a powerful graphics card to an *unbranded* PSU *below* the recommended wattage" - the implication is that the PSU failed.

Comment: I agree with both previous comments that it is likely that the PSU died. When I PSU dies it might act in a non regular way, taking other components with it.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the components in the PSU were to fail in such a way that it created a short, it would cause significant damage to connected devices.

> unbranded PSU

Never buy unbranded. If you don't know the source you don't know the build quality.